# Apache URL internal redirect prepends last URL first node name in current url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rewriting the url for a shopping site and want to make the url SEO friendly.
ex: /topcatName/ChildCatName?cid=23 to /product/index.php?cid=23

I used following code

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=([0-9]*)$
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product/index.php?cid=%1 [L]
```

This rule is prepending first node name to next url.

ex:
    if user naviagates from 
/topcatName/ChildCatName?cid=23 to /nexttopcatName/nextChildCatName?cid=23, browser url will show /topcatName/nexttopcatName/nextChildCatName?cid=23

/topcatName is not expected in next url. Expected url is /nexttopcatName/nextChildCatName?cid=23.
Somehow, apache is retaining first node name in next url and it keeps prepending for every click.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?